# C++ functor passing through recursion: "attempt to use a deleted function"

Tags: c++11, recursion, functor

## Context

Assessment piece for a data structures and algorithms course, an exercise in using an AVL tree and hash table to parse input to create a dictionary file and then use that file to perform cursory spell checking.
**N.B.:** I am *not* asking for help in solving this problem that's not what I'm having difficulty with. I am asking for help understanding an aspect of C++ function object passing/usage that is causing me considerable frustration. This aspect of C++ is not part of the assessment, there are no marks attached to it, I simply have a personal issue submitting code I dislike the design of.

## Problem

Passing a functor to a recursive function results in compiler error, "attempt to use a deleted function." I thought this was an issue with passing the functor by value, so I changed the parameter to pass by reference which yields a, "no matching member function for call to *<public member function of AVL tree that kicks off the recursion>*," in which case I don't know how to alter the function declaration so it does match. I have also tried making the parameter: `const UnaryFunction& action` (a constant function-object reference), but this yields the compiler error, "`no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::__1::__mem_fn<void (DictGen::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char> &)>'`," in which case I can't understand why it wouldn't be matching to the DictGen::output signature.

### Code

Relevant parts of AVL tree class:

```
template <class T>
struct AVLNode
{ // simple data carrier node for AVL tree
    AVLNode<T>* lChild;
    AVLNode<T>* rChild;
    AVLBalance balFac;
    T data;
};

template <class T>
class AVLTree<T>
{
    ...

    AVLNode<T>* root;

    template <class UnaryFunction>
    void inorderAction( AVLNode<T>* node, UnaryFunction action )
    {
        if ( node != NULL )
        {
            inorderAction( node->lChild, action );
            action( node->data ); // << problem line
            inorderAction( node->rChild, action );
        }
    }

public:
    template <class UnaryFunction>
    void inorder( UnaryFunction action )
    {
        inorderAction( root, action );
    }
}
```

Relevant parts of DictGen class:

```
class DictGen
{
    ...

    FILE* outStream;
    AVLTree<std::string> dict;

    void output( std::string& word )
    {
        fprintf( outstream, "%s\n", word.c_str() );
    }

public:
    goGoGadgetDictionaryGenerator()
    {
        ...

        dict.inorder( std::mem_fn( &DictGen::output ) ); // << also problem line
    }
}
```

#### Interpretation/Translation

AVL tree class has a flexible inorder traversal that allows me to action the node however I want with the given `UnaryFunction action`. A DictGen object is initialised with a FILE* so DictGen instances may output to different files, hence the need to pass a member function object in the `dict.inorder( ... )` call.

## Efforts/research so far

My initial solution was to follow the functions as parameters example given in our textbook which involved using C function pointers and polluting global space. Although this worked I was unsatisfied with this design; I wished to bundle this behaviour in a DictGen class.
My after consulting both my lecturer and lab tutor they suggested using C++ functors but weren't able to help with implementation as neither had used functors in a while.
I forged ahead finding very handy material on SO (helping me reference a member function), several functor tutorials via Google and an excellent PDF from a Stanford course regarding functor implementation and usage. However, while all these resources have carried me this far, none have been able to shed any light on my current predicament. I was really hoping making the parameter a `const UnaryFunction&` would solve it but can't understand why the signature doesn't match.

I have also tried using an inline lambda but require the object context to access `outStream`.

I have spent the last four days ploughing away at this issue and the only remaining lead I have is an SO post that casually remarked that the C++ spec contains information about the implicit deletion of function objects but I haven't been able to make any further progress. If there is an SO post that solves my issue, I haven't been able to find it.

## Questions

Does the recursion really have anything to do with this issue?
Is there some novice aspect of functor passing/usage I'm not grasping?
What is causing the function to be deleted?
What am I missing about getting the function signatures to match when it appears that function deletion isn't the issue?

This is my very first SO post, I have done my best to keep the question-asking suggestions in mind. I welcome any constructive criticism to help me improve this post so that I can it can both solve my issue and serve as a future resource for similar issues.

Comment: This is an exception first question! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: We also need to see AVLNode because you are passing `node->data` to `action()` but it isn't clear what `node->data` is

Comment: `std::mem_fn( &DictGen::output )` is a binary functor, which expects a reference or pointer to `DictGen`, and then a reference to `std::string`.

Comment: @KennyEvitt thank you kindly, I put considerable effort into it in the hope of maintaining the quality of SO content I depend upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coding in C++11.  While there are uses for `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind`, they are a very awkward way to generate these kind of functors.

```
void gen()
{
    dict.inorder(
      [this]( std::string& word ) { this->output(word); }
    );
}
```

while the lambda syntax might be somewhat new to you, this is far less backwards than the `std::bind( std::mem_fn( &T::method ), this, std::placeholders::_1)`

The basic syntax of a lambda is:

```
 [capture-list]( arguments )->return value { code }
```

where capture-list is `[=]` (auto-capture by value) or `[&]` (auto-capture by reference) or `[var1, var2]` (capture var1 and var2 by value) or `[&var1, &var2]` (capture var1 and var2 by reference) or a mixture of same.  (C++1y adds new syntax, like `[x = std::move(y)]`)

`(arguments)` are just a usual function argument bit.  It is actually optional, but required if you want a return value.

`-> return value` is optional for single-statement lambdas, or lambdas that return `void`.  (In C++1y, it is optional even with multiple returns)

Then the code.

Comment: thank you, this works too. I quite like this solution. I find the context and argument declaration easier to comprehend over rewrapping the function object with a placeholder. When researching the topic area the literature was overwhelmingly weighted towards function pointers and function objects; and the few examples of lambdas that did pop up didn't have anything in the capture list, exactly what was missing. What search terms should I have been using to have good lambda examples emerge? Can you recommend a good C++11 lambda resource?

Comment: @exceptionAl [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#lambda) at Bjarn's page and [C++11 FAQ](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#lambda) at isocpp are probably decent places to start.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have an instance of DictGen bound to the member function:

```
    // ...
    void gen()
    {
        dict.inorder(
          std::bind( std::mem_fn( &DictGen::output ), 
                     this,  std::placeholders::_1) );
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Smashing! This is just the sort of C++ prowess I was hoping for. When researching `<functional>` I came across `bind` but it didn't jump out as a solution. @perreal, may I ask you to explain why binding was necessary? What is it about this situation that requires rewrapping a member function object in another function object?  When I'd identified the need for `mem_fn` and figured out it's argument I'd assumed `&DictGen::` gave it the _instance-ness_ it required (I had also tried `&( this->output )`).

Comment: @exceptionAl, member functions are only callable on active instances. When you do `&DictGen::output`, you get the function address only. If you want to use this pointer, you need to provide an instance address as the first parameter (which becomes `this` in the function body) .

Comment: My lecturer has just imposed an assignment-wide C++98 restriction - this is weeks after the assignment specification first went live and after happily accepting C++11 submissions for previous assessment pieces. I'm refactoring my source and I've spent the day wrestling with C++98 bind1st and mem_fun/mem_fun_ref but without success. Are you able to shed some light on how to make your answer C++98 compatible?